# i am getting index out of range error on running the below code

Tags: go

i having the following code to print the indexes of an array which contains similar values.

but on running this code getting panic: indexes out of range run time error

why i am getting this

package main

```
import "fmt"

func main()  {
    var numbers[] int = [] int {5,2,3,5,3}
    var copy_numbers[] int
    var count [5] int
    var i,j int
    copy(copy_numbers,numbers)
    for i=0;i<len(numbers);i++ {
        for j=0;j<len(numbers) ;j++  {
            if numbers[i]==numbers[j] {
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d",count)

    for i=0;i<len(numbers) ;i++  {
        fmt.Println("hello")
        if count[i]>1{
            for j=0;j<len(numbers) ;j++  {
                if numbers[i]==copy_numbers[j] {

                    fmt.Printf("%d",j)

                }
            }
            fmt.Println("")
        }
    }

fmt.Printf("%d",count)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy_numbers` is of size 0, just as you initialized it.

If I add the following before your first for loop:

```
fmt.Println(numbers)
fmt.Println(copy_numbers)
```

I get:

```
[5 2 3 5 3]
[]
```

the [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) builtin copies up to the length of either argument, as mentioned in the docs:

> Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum
>   of len(src) and len(dst).

You should initialize `copy_numbers` to be of the same length as `numbers`

```
  copy_numbers := make([]int, len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

`len(copy_numbers)` is zero because `copy` will only copy `min(len(src), len(dst))` elements and `copy_numbers` length is zero.

Use this line to define a bigger `copy_numbers` so `copy` does what you want:

```
copy_numbers[] := make([]int, len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentaion:

> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may overlap. Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum of len(src) and len(dst).

in your case, the destination is `copy_numbers`, which is an uninitialized slice. To initialize it, and have enough space to hold a copy of `numbers` you can simply do

`copy_numbers := make([]int, len(numbers)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you've used `copy`. From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy):

> Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum
>   of len(src) and len(dst).

The manner in which you are creating `copy_numbers` initializes it with a zero length.

```
var copy_numbers []int // len(copy_numbers) == 0
```

This causes `copy` to not copy a single element from `numbers`.

To fix this, you can change `copy_numbers` initialization to:

```
copy_numbers := make([]int, len(numbers))
```

The rest of the code should work.